# In Flutter ThemeData and InputDecordation, what does the focusColor property do?

Tags: flutter

I've read the `focusColor` documentation and tried to experiment with the property, but can't get that property to affect anything on the screen.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/focusColor.html

I assumed it would change the fill color of an input to the focus color when you select that input box.

Are there any examples of what this property is supposed to do?

Comment: yes it only changes the color of the input field when you select that input field ,I don't think it's that hard to make a tutorial for it , it's just colors and styles you can play with at as you want , but a tutorial for the themeData class is necessary for making beautiful and well maintained app's UI

Comment: I'm using `TextFormField` and the `focusColor` property doesn't seem to have any effect.  All the other properties I've tried are working as I'd expect, except `focusColor`.